# search function with clickable dropdown popup

Tags: jquery, html

I dont want the popup showing after i click an item in the dropdown search.

i just want it to go directly to the link when clicked..

can someone help me out with this?

```
var source = [ { value: "www.foo.com",
             label: "Spencer Kline"
           },
           { value: "www.example.com",
             label: "James Bond"
           },
           ...
         ];    

var source = [ { value: "http://www.foo.com",
             label: "Spencer Kline"
           },
           { value: "http://www.example.com",
             label: "James Bond"
           }
         ];

$("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: source,
    select: function( event, ui ) { 
        alert(ui.item.value);
        window.location.href = ui.item.value;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/MzsyY/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the line `alert(ui.item.value);` from your code.

`alert(...)` triggers a popup window, you can read more about them [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp).

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the alert.

It should be this way

```
var source = [ { value: "http://www.foo.com",
                 label: "Spencer Kline"
               },
               { value: "http://www.example.com",
                 label: "James Bond"
               }
             ];

    $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: source,
        select: function( event, ui ) { 
            window.location.href = ui.item.value;
        }
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DiegoTc/MzsyY/495/